# Parse Response Variable Issues with HTTP Request and Cloud Code

Tags: parse-platform, httprequest, response, parse-cloud-code

I am trying to run an HTTP Request in an afterSave. It executes correctly, but im getting errors with the response variable I was told to put in the end.

Here is the code

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("ArtPiece", function(request) {
var artistURL = 'http://www.gallery-admin-dev.iartview.com/Gilmans/imageSave.php';

var artPiece = request.object;

if (typeof request.image === "undefined") {

    var pieceName = artPiece.get("piece_name");

    var url = artPiece.get("imageURL");

    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        url: artistURL,
        params: {
          pieceName : pieceName,
          url : url
        },
        success: function(httpResponse) {
            response.success();
        },
        error: function(httpResponse) {
            response.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status)
        }
    }); 
}
});
```

The problem is the success and error functions.

Things I have tried that have not worked:
Putting response as a second parameter in the afterSave Call (it says can not call .success of an undefined variable)

Getting rid of the response lines of code (Result: success/error was not called)

Calling Response as its own function response('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status) it just says response is undefined.

I dont really care about having any response or not, I just want the code to work properly.

How is this 'response' variable supposed to be set up?

Thank you!

Comment: How do you know the code, (as is), is failing?

Comment: It doesnt always fail, it usually gets about half of the art_pieces done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an extra url in the parameters, a reference to a probably undefined `artistURL`...

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("ArtPiece", function(request) {
    var artistURL = 'http://www.gallery-admin-dev.iartview.com/Gilmans/imageSave.php';
    var artPiece = request.object;
    if (typeof request.image === "undefined") {
        var pieceName = artPiece.get("piece_name");
        var url = artPiece.get("imageURL");
        var params = { pieceName : pieceName };
        return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({ url: artistURL, params: params });
    }
});
```

Comment: Awesome suggestion!

unforunately I still get: Result: TypeError: Cannot call method 'error' of undefined.

Could this be some type of timeout issue?


it still is thinking response is undefined regardless

Comment: No.  Its my bad.  *after* save doesn't take a response param.  before does.  Sorry about this.  Maybe it was the syntax error in the OP function.  Please see edit.

Comment: No problem, Thank you, 

The second url is actually necessary to the params, but I added it back myself. Now there are no errors, but still some of the images are not showing up for some reason. I will have to do more research to see why, but having no errors is helpful

Comment: Im a the point where I get: 'Result: Execution timed out' and 'Result: success/error was not called' in the error logs. Is it possible I am missing a call to success or error

Comment: Ok good. Now we have a clear diagnosis. Try executing that req in a browser or with CURL and see what's going on.